# select signal from each bus in array of busses

Tags: arrays, matlab, simulink, bus

In the first part of my Simulink model I created a bus array as described in the [official documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/work-with-array-of-buses-signals.html) from `n` separate, but equally defined busses.

For the second part I need to get one of the bus signals from each bus in the array. I managed to do so with a MATLAB Function block by iterating through the array elements and copying the data to new arrays. Unfortunately I have to implement it without MATLAB Function blocks.

Is there a way to extract a single signal from all `n` busses in the bus array without using `n` selector blocks like in the [documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/work-with-array-of-buses-signals.html) (image below: *Selector4* and *Selector5*)?

Consider `n` arbitrarily large so that an implementation with selector blocks is unacceptable.

[image: MATLAB Documentation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. It is possible to put a bus selector inside a *For Each* subsystem:

[image]

This will result in `n`-dimensional output arrays.